# SFMC REST API - Cloud Pages & Collections

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, landing-page, content-builder

I've successfully used the available REST API in order to create various assets in Marketing Cloud, like HTML Emails, Templates, and Landing Pages.

The email assets are visible under the appropriate category and section of the Content Builder UI, however, the Landing Pages are not.

Attempting to fetch them shows that they do exist on the system though. The only problem I see is that normally landing pages need to be contained in "Collections" that the user needs to create beforehand.

There currently is no reference in any of the available fields pertaining to this information. Is there an alternative I am not seeing perhaps?

Are Collections for Cloud Pages somehow retrievable through REST even?